# System will not boot because boot partition is missing?

Tags: boot, grub2, data-recovery, rescue

I deleted my boot partition several day ago and have not been able to recover it. To fix it, I installed the same image with the same parameters on a flash drive and then copied that boot partition on to my hard drive. I am now getting an error that indicates that the vmlinuz image searches for the root partition by uuid and it can find my hard drive. To make things more complicated, my hd is lvm+LUKS. Can I edit vmlinuz and initrd.img? Is there another way to fix this? Or should I abandon it and reinstall?

I am using 32-bit Debian Jessie and am able to access all remaining files on my hard drive.

Edit--I don't have my old vmlinuz or initrd.img, they were deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Your boot parameters are handled by your boot loader passing an argument to vmlinuz when it launches. Assuming you are using grub, in `grub.cfg` there will be an argument for `root=` that should contain your UUID. Since your using LUKS the more difficult part is that there is probably an initramfs image that boots at startup and actually mounts and decrypts your partition and could quite possibly have the UUID stored inside the image.

The easiest recovery for this is to find a live distro with LUKS support and boot from it (Debian install typically has a recovery mode at livecd boot). Then mount your encrypted root, decrypt, mount boot and then chroot into the mounted partitions. Once in there you can rerun the ramdisk utility and see if that updates all your info. Make sure you mount `/boot` too before chrooting.

```
update-initramfs -c -k <kernel>
update-grub
```

Exit chroot, unmounted everything and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

1) Boot from live CD

2) Create boot partition again like ext4

3) Install Linux images on your boot partition

`sudo mount /dev/sdax /mnt/myroot` (where sdax is your root partition)

`sudo mount /dev/sday /mnt/myroot/boot`  (we need to mount boot because it is on another partition /dev/sday)

```
sudo mount ‐‐bind /dev /mnt/myroot/dev
sudo mount ‐‐bind /proc /mnt/myroot/proc
sudo mount ‐‐bind /sys /mnt/myroot/sys
```

Mount all of your other partitions `/boot`,`/var`,`/usr`,`/tmp` etc. Make sure you have mounted them all.

Copy resolv.conf

```
cp -L /etc/resolve.conf /mnt/debian-example/etc/resolve.conf
```

chroot

```
 sudo chroot /media/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin /mnt/tmp...
```

Reinstall missing kernel image

*move initrd.img from root:*

```
mv initrd.img initrd.img.OLD
```

install Linux image

```
apt-cache search 'linux-image'
apt-get install linux-image-x.x-generic
```

Replace `linux-image-x.x-generic` with yours.

restore grub

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the **root partition is not mounted by default**.
Where one has to mount manually through the **shell root prompt** of advance boot options using the command by pressing `ctrl+alt+f3 | f4 | f5` while booting.

1. perform a thorough `fsck` on all partitions before mounting. `lsblk` will show you all the partition names.
2. `fsck /dev/{partition-name}`
3. remount all the partitions with read-write access
   `mount -n -0 remount, rw /`
4. type `exit` and **resume** your boot without **rebooting**
5. you should be able to login by now.

For a **permanent solution**, one has to find the **root partition** 
 6. using command `lsblk`
   or manually finding from the directory /dev/your-root-partition. you can cat /etc/fstab to find the root partition
It will say

```
# / was on /dev/{your-partition-name} during installation
```

7. edit the `fstab` in the `/etc/fstab`
   to mount the root partition while booting automatically with **rw access** and add

   `/dev/{your-boot-directory} / ext3 rw 0 1`
8. **save the file** and update your grub

   `sudo update-grub`
9. `reboot` now it should login as normal.

**Credits:**

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=118114

[System will not boot because boot partition is missing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264598/system-will-not-boot-because-boot-partition-is-missing)

https://geek-university.com/linux/etc-fstab-file/

https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount