# Make changes to busybox/initramfs that are persistent?

Tags: boot, luks, busybox, initramfs, rescue

I am in the process of recovering my 32-bit Debian Jessie box with a lvm+LUKS disk. I am coming back from a system that had a root partition but no boot partition. Grub executes, but either vmlinuz or initramfs causes issues. A message is displayed that indicates that none of the volumes can be found. I have regenerated initramfs. I am then given a busybox/initramfs prompt. From this prompt, I can edit /conf/conf.d/cryptroot to reference my hard disk by UUID and boot into my OS, albeit in rescue mode.

See this question for more context: [System will not boot because boot partition is missing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264598/system-will-not-boot-because-boot-partition-is-missing/264610#264610)

How can I regenerate/replace my vmlinuz and make changes to initramfs persistent? Or is there another solution?

Comment: The way to update the initramfs is by running `update-initramfs` from the booted system, as you were told in the other thread. What more are you looking for with this question?

Comment: I am still missing vmlinuz and initramfs needs to be coaxed to boot into my OS. And even then I still only have emergency mode.